# What does the second parameter in std::vector.resize() mean?

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I'm having some problems understanding what `const value_type& val` means in this function:

```
void std::vector::resize (size_type n, const value_type& val);
```

I read the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) and here's what it says:

> Object whose content is copied to the added elements in case that n is greater than the current container size.
>   If not specified, the default constructor is used instead.
>   Member type value_type is the type of the elements in the container, defined in vector as an alias of the first template parameter (T).

But what exactly does it do? For example I have this line of code:

```
myVector.resize(10, numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
```

The content of infinity is copied to `myVector` if 10 is bigger than its current size?

If someone could please explain, that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: I honestly don't see how that description is unclear. Yes, the object you pass as the second argument is used to fill in the last `10 - myVector.size()` elements.

Comment: The C++ reference states "If n is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of val, otherwise, they are value-initialized.".  So yes, `val` is used to initialize any new elements added to the vector.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sets all the values in the vector to that value, so if `myVector` is empty to begin with, it would contain 10 doubles, with infinity as the value. If you already have the values 1.3, 2.9, 3.6, -1.9 and 5.2 in the vector, the next five elements will be infinity.

Obviously, it makes no difference if you have a value there or what the value is, if the vector was already bigger than 10 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `resize()` function can be used to increase or decrease the size of the vector. However, if you use it to increse the size (if the new size is greater than the current size), *something* has to go in those new cells. If you don't specify the second parameter then this value is the default constructor for whatever data type the vector holds; however, you can use the second parameter to specify what that default value should be. Common uses of this are to specify a value of `0`, `NULL`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Despite some elaborate language, it's pretty simple. If the resize creates new elements, then of course they have to be initialized with something. Normally, for a `vector<T>`, they will be initialized by invoking the default constructor of `T`. Providing that second argument will instead initialize the new elements to copies of that value.

In your example, indeed, the call ensures that the vector has 10 items, and if it had less than that, all new items receive a copy of `infinity`. So if your vector had 6 elements, it will get 4 new copies of `infinity`.